# Frequency for duplicate items in a list C#

Tags: c#, list, count, duplicates, windows

I'm on VS Windows Forms Application and I'm NOT using any other form of coding (e.g. linq) - just the basic style of coding which goes like this;

```
List<string> brandList = new List<string>();
//brand items are added to the list

//go through list
for(int i = 0; brandList.Count; i++)
{
if(brandList[i]== "BrandName1")
{
//count for that brandName
}
}
```

What I want to know is how to I get the count for how many times a brand has occurred in the list?

This code will not need to be case sensitive either because it is being read in from a file..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want/can't use LINQ you could use a `Dictionary<string, int>`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for(int i = 0; brandList.Count; i++)
{
    string brand = brandList[i];
    int count = 1;
    if(dict.ContainsKey(brand))
        count = dict[brand] + 1;
    dict[brand] = count;
}
```

Now you have all brands as key and their counts as value.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see the problem because your code is already have the solution if I understand correctly the question. You go through the elements, if the current element is the element to count you increment a variable.

```
const string BRAND = "BrandName1";
int count = 0;
foreach (string brand in brandList)
{
    if (string.Compare(brand, BRAND, true))
    {
       count++;
    }
}
```

Obviously you can use `for (int i = 0; i < brandList.Count; i++)` and `brandList[i]` instead of `foreach`, but it's more like C#.

Comment: How do I get the item in the list with the highest count?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
List<string> brandList = new List<string>();
//brand items are added to the list

//sort list to get number of occurences of each entry
brandList.Sort();

var occurences = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
//go through list
var numBrand = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < brandList.Count-1; i++)
{
    if (string.Equals(brandList[i + 1], brandList[i]))
    {
        numBrand++;
    }
    else
    {
        occurences.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(brandList[i], numBrand));
        numBrand = 1;
    }
}
var highestCount = occurences.OrderBy(o => o.Value).ToList()[0].Key;
```

It might skip the last entry if that is a single occurences but then that's not the highest anyway.
Would that do the trick for you?